# Circularity: To use pip I should get virtualenv (which requires pip)

Tags: python, pip

The page on http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html says that, "The easiest way to install and use pip is with virtualenv,...."

In that passage, "virtualenv" has been helpfully linked to the http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/ page.  Whereby I'm thus informed that I can, "install globally with pip (if you have pip 1.3 or greater installed globally)":

```
$ [sudo] pip install virtualenv
```

So I can't win.

I've got a cobrateam.info Splinter directory full of Splinter app files that's temporarily burning a hole on my desktop that I'd like to install, for lack of a better word, to be used in the Python setting.  I'm using Windows 7.

(BTW, I don't know what '[sudo]' at the front of the command line above means.  And I'm a Python noob.)

Please help me with this circular pip, virtualenv thing.  Anytime I invoke pip on the command line, there's an error suggestive of the machine not knowing what pip is.  (But I can get to a Python working area just fine by typing python and hitting return, which brings me to a '>>>', no fewer than three '>'s.)

Thanks.

Comment: `[]` in most command syntax descriptions indicates that the bracketed text is optional. So `[sudo]` means that you may not need to include `sudo` in the command. For example if you are already root, or if the location you are installing to is in your user directory.

Comment: @kindall The OP is using Windows 7

Comment: Would you be happy just installing a Windows binary installer package for `virtualenv` to get you bootstrapped? It doesn't directly answer your question, but it will probably make your life easier. (I added that to the end of my answer, if you need details.)

Comment: In that case `sudo` would *definitely* be optional.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of four different methods in the instructions to install `virtualenv`. What's stopping you from using one of the other ones?

In fact, the site specifically says in a few different places that you should use `pip` if you already have pip 1.3 or later, use the source install if you don't have `pip` or have 1.2 or earlier.

So, just follow the other instructions:

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ [sudo] python setup.py install
```

---

The `[sudo]` is a convention meaning "Type whatever command you need to run the rest of this as root, which is `sudo` on most setups on most Unix systems."

On Windows, there is no such thing as `sudo`; `runas` or `start` with appropriate flags is the closest substitute, but usually you don't need it at all—and, if you do, it's usually easier to just use the "open command prompt as adminstrator" instead of the normal "open command prompt", and then you can run the command without any extra words.

---

Note that Windows, only most other systems/distributions, doesn't come with `curl` or `tar` either. If you haven't already installed these yourself, it may be easiest to just download the URL with your web browser, double-click the resulting file in Explorer to expand it (if this just gives you a single `virtualenv-X.X.tar` file instead of a `virtualenv-X.X` directory, you will need to double-click the `.tar` file too), and only do the last step from the command line.

---

Finally, since you're on Windows, if you're using one of the standard Python binary installations from python.org, it may be easier to use [Christoph Gohlke's binary Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#virtualenv) to get started. Just download and run the appropriate `virtualenv` installer, and now you'll have a `virtualenv` with `pip` in it.

---

Even more finallier, notice that installing `virtualenv` will *not* install a global `pip`. The docs you quoted say:

> The easiest way to install and use pip is with virtualenv, since every virtualenv has pip (and it’s dependencies) installed into it automatically.

If you're going to work entirely with virtual environments (which is often the most convenient way to work, once you get used to it), this is exactly what you want. Use the `pip` that comes with each new virtual environment you create to set up that environment.

But if you don't want to use virtual environments, or want to use them sometimes but not all the time, you will need a global `pip`. The instructions for that are immediately after the "Using virtualenv" section you quotes, so just follow them. But briefly:

- Download and run [`ez_setup.py`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) to get `setuptools`.
- Download and run [`get-pip.py`](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) to get `pip`.
- There is no step three.

Or, of course, you can download and run the binary packages from the same repository above, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for your help (and to all who answered above as well, thanks).  The feedback I get after writing python setup.py install is "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools"  And I don't know what that means.

Comment: I'll try your last, Gohlke, link.  Hoping for the best.

Comment: I'm sorry, there's no evidence pip is working on anything.  Nothing I run recognizes pip as a valid statement even after downloading and installing Christoph Gohlke's binary Python Extension Packages for Windows.  I even turned my machine off and back on and tried invoking pip, with no luck.

Comment: Installing `virtualenv` doesn't install `pip` globally, it installs `pip` in each virtual environment. If you don't want to use virtual environments (or want to use them sometimes, but also want a global `pip`), then you'll need to install a global `pip`. I believe Gohlke has that as well, or you can use the instructions for installing a global `pip` (which is just to download and run the [`get-pip.py`](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) script).

Comment: I downloaded the global pip and installed that.  I'm getting this now at the command line when I try to:  >pip install splinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Comment: @user225626: First, did you also install `setuptools`? If not, do that. If you… then you have a new problem, and will need to ask a new question, where you will have to give the full output of the `pip` command and the log file it refers to. (In that question, explain how you installed Python, setuptools, and pip, and give the version numbers for everything, and link to this question, to avoid people asking you to repeat a bunch of stuff you've already had to explain once.)

Comment: Actually, before creating a new question, search to see if it's already been asked and answered, because I'm sure it has. (Just one note: if anyone refers to `distribute`, that's obsolete, and `setuptools` is its successor.)

Comment: abarnert, the scripts you pointed me to got pip installed for me.  Thank you.  This has been an adventure, I've learned quite a bit.  I appreciate all of your patience and instruction.

Comment: @user225626: A few years from now, everything you need will be in the stdlib. A few years ago, nobody was even thinking about stdlibifying `virtualenv`, `pip`, or `distribute`/`setuptools` and the documentation encouraged the "hacky" way of doing things that's still necessary for a little bit longer. But in 2013, we're right in the middle, probably the worst possible time to get into this… Or, if you're looking at it as an adventure rather than a trial, the best time. :)